# Cocos2d js Asset Management

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I am new to cocos2d-js and using 3.2 version. In Asset Manager its given that you can download the js file, so can we replace the file main.js, app.js? Also changing the game logic through Assets Manager update?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Assets manager extension is designed for hot update of images, audio files and game scripts used in your game. You will be able to update a new version of resources on your web server, your game can keep track your remote resources and download them into the device. An entire new design, new experience or even new contents could be instantly available without needing to update your application on every app store.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/creator/manual/en/advanced-topics/assets-manager.html

The only thing that I doubt is `main.js`, because the way its loaded, main.js file will be loaded after frameworks/Cocos2d-html5/CCBoot.js file and it will initialize the configuration and load all the JavaScript files specified by modules and jsList in the project.json file, so basically Downloading of your new contents with manager can happen only after main.js is loaded.